# Loop for select array in php and html form

Tags: php, html

I have a (Coffee) form that contains 60 `select` tags and each `select` tag has 16 `options` that contains numbers from 0 to 15.
like this :

```
<label><select name="item[0][breakfast_blend]">
                              <option value="0">0</option>
                              <option value="1">1</option>
                              <option value="2">2</option>
                              <option value="3">3</option>
                              <option value="4">4</option>
                              <option value="5">5</option>
                              <option value="6">6</option>
                              <option value="7">7</option>
                              <option value="8">8</option>
                              <option value="9">9</option>
                              <option value="10">10</option>
                              <option value="11">11</option>
                              <option value="12">12</option>
                              <option value="13">13</option>
                              <option value="14">14</option>
                              <option value="15">15</option>
</select>Breakfast Blend</label>
<label><select name="item[1][tea]">
                              <option value="0">0</option>
                              <option value="1">1</option>
                              <option value="2">2</option>
                              <option value="3">3</option>
                              <option value="4">4</option>
                              <option value="5">5</option>
                              <option value="6">6</option>
                              <option value="7">7</option>
                              <option value="8">8</option>
                              <option value="9">9</option>
                              <option value="10">10</option>
                              <option value="11">11</option>
                              <option value="12">12</option>
                              <option value="13">13</option>
                              <option value="14">14</option>
                              <option value="15">15</option>
</select>Tea</label>
```

> There are 60 other selects like this with other labels.

now I'm trying to set a condition to check to see which items are selected by the user, then take the value of the **option** and the **label** of that select.

so i create a `if` condition to check the value of the selected item but i don't know how to get the label of that item (I mean i don't know how to contain it in the loop).
here is my code in php part :

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= count($_POST['item']); $i++) {
    if (isset($_POST['item'][$i])) {
        echo $_POST['item'][$i];
    }
}
```

> some of my friends told that `Foreach` function could help but still i don't know how :/

any help to contain the **label** in the loop ??

Comment: Why are you making them all 1 array? If you give them each a unique nameit will be much easier for you.

Comment: the label value does not get posted back to the server. Your server will need to understand based on the name attribute what the human-readable description should be. Either you have to hard-code it, or you can use some kind of lookup table.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton then how i should use it in loop ? @_@

Comment: `foreach($_POST as $value)`

Comment: @ADyson i just add a simply code but important part of the code, i had post it to the server and its working fine

Comment: I don't really know what you mean by that. What important thing did you add? And what exactly worked as a result? To judge by your other comments you still have a problem with getting a human-readable version of the field name. In which case my previous comment is still true - it isn't sent to the server as part of the POST variables. So you need to use some kind of lookup or hard-coding of the descriptions for the purpose of putting it into your email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like that

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= count($_POST['item']); $i++) {
if (isset($_POST['item'][$i])) {
    foreach($_POST['item'][$i] as $cle => $value){
     $label =  ucwords(str_replace("_"," ",$cle));
     $item = $value;
     echo  $label." ".$item;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the breakfast blend and tea from the name if you include it you have to echo the value of item[0][breakfast_blend] now in your code it is echoing item[0] which not give you value

```
<select name="item[0]">
<select name="item[1]">
```

Comment: so how i can get each 'label' of the selected items ? the point is, i want to send it an email.

Comment: Within your php create array which hold the name of label index 0 is breakfast_blend and index 1is tea and so on